# I want to do a three-way ANOVA of the mean amount of accidents under specific speed limits by region but I don't know if it is possible

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mean

[image]

The image attached shows the amount of accidents per speed limit by year for 1 region. I have two other tables showing similar data. I want to do a three-way ANOVA on these sets of data to see if there is any variance in the mean amount of accidents under each speed limit compared to each of the regions I am looking at.

My issue is that, are we able to assume that there is independence in the number of accidents that occur in one year compared to that of another? Because I believe this is something called "Time series" but I have no knowledge of that yet. However, my professor did say 3-way ANOVA is possible but it just doesn't seem right to me because I *feel* like the independence assumption might be violated.